# Does it construct twice if I autowire in two places?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In Spring, I have a @Service bean to initialize it:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

If then I use @Autowired to use the bean above in two different classes, will the 'init' be executed twice or only once? I hope it only executes once, because my initialization of the bean is heavy.

Also, is it always good to use @PostConstruct to initialize a bean? So far I have been always doing this.

Comment: The @PostConstruct is executed once per instance. The number of instances is dependent on the scope of the bean. By default in spring is a singleton, so the init is called just once.

Comment: That's great! only once.

Answer (score 1):

That depends if your bean is scoped prototype or singleton.

See [bean scopes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes)

You should consider using constructors instead wherever possible. To keep everything easier testable and reduce complexity.